# This is the code i have written in android studio.It shows Cannot find symbol class TextView.It also Shows Package R does not exist

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments

```
package com.example.android.favoritetoys;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // TODO (1) Declare a TextView variable called mToysListTextView
    TextView mToysListTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mToysListTextView = (TextView).findViewById(R.id.tv_toy_names);
        // TODO (3) Use findViewById to get a reference to the TextView from the layout

        // TODO (4) Use the static ToyBox.getToyNames method and store the names in a String array
        String[] toyNames = ToyBox.getToyNames();
        // TODO (5) Loop through each toy and append the name to the TextView (add \n for spacing)
        for (String toyName : toyNames) {
            mToysListTextView.append(toyName + "\n\n\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your build.gradle file. there you will find the code given below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.example.favoritetoys"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
}
```

You have to do just change it buildToolsVersion '25.0.2' to according your "build Tool Version".
    mine is working with      **strong text**buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

Answer (score 0):

you need to import one last class, just add

```
 import android.widget.TextView;
```